# How to make xprop -set manual changes permanent

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, metacity

I am trying to permanently reserve space for my top edge panel in the middle of a dual display screen, where the two monitors are above and under each other, like this (the smaller lower one has the panels):

(I use Gnome Flashback Metacity with composition enabled on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|               |
|               |
|-----------+---+
|'''''''''''|
|           |
|,,,,,,,,,,,|
+-----------+
```

I [managed to find out](http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.hu/2015/01/how-to-reserve-space-for-panel-between.html) how I can manually reserve space for the panel with `xprop -id [window id] -f _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL [strut dimensions]`.

EDIT3: now I [have a script](http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.hu/2015/01/how-to-reserve-space-for-panel-between.html#script) that automatically calculates the position of the "floating" panel and sets the strut.

By running this command, the space for the panel gets reserved exactly until I press the Application or the Places menu, or an application launcher. This only happens with this two menus, while the indicator area drop down menus do not reverse the manual change.

EDIT2: this too happens if I add a folder bookmark in Nemo (I use Nemo instead of Nautilus/Files). It looks like it has something to do with reloading the content of the Nemo sidebar, because no other menu selection triggers this change.

**How can I prevent these menus to cancel the manual change I made with xprop -set?**

EDIT: I tried out with and without composition enabled and it is the same.